# “Troja hat es wirklich gegeben” – Can I leave “es” out?

Tags: pronoun, expletiva

I am trying to understand more and more how the particle *es* works. I know that sometimes when the subject is not completely explicit, or when there is none, then I am supposed to use *es.* 
I am not really comfortable with using this particle, as I am never sure how to.

For example, is *es* necessary in the following sentence? Or could I omit it and nothing would change?

> Troja hat es wirklich gegeben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you can not leave out the *es*.

> Troja hat wirklich gegeben

is not a "complete" sentence.

It is a reordered version of

> Es hat Troja wirklich gegeben

and you can not leave the *es* out here either. This is because Troja in this example is not the subject of the sentence, but really an accusative object. This is different to

> Troja hat wirklich existiert

where Troja is really the subject of the sentence.

It is a bit like asking whether you can omit the *there* in

> There was a time when I spoke no German at all

---

Maybe the problem is the difference between the English an German way of saying it. In English you'd say:

> Troja really existed

which would translate to

> Troja existierte wirklich (or more colloquially: Troja hat wirklich existiert)

In this case, Troja is the subject of the sentence.

The German

> Troja hat es wirklich gegeben

would translate to

> There really was Troja

which nobody would say in English, but the expressions are equivalent.

Comment: I don´t really understand why Troja is not the subject in the first sentence. What kind of verb usage it that?

Comment: Well, the basic expression is *es gibt* (*there is*). *es* is the subject. We then put it in past tense: *es gab*. The next question is *es gab wen oder was?", because *es gab* is not a complete sentence, really. The answer to this might be "Troja", so "Troja" really in accusative case: *es gab Troja*. To put emphasis on the fact that it existed in reality, you add *wirklich* (*really*), and you end up with *es gab Troja wirklich*.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.nthuleen.com/102/hausaufgaben/explnomakkdat.html