# Welche Art von "es" liegt vor in "Es sind Ferien."?

Tags: grammar-identification

Soweit ich weiß ist `Ferien sind es.` nicht richtig, wenn wir von "Es sind Ferien" ausgehen, wobei "es" zu nichts im Kontext/Text referrieren kann.

Dann könnte man das "es" weder als Referenten noch als unpersönliches "es" werten, weil beide diese Umstellung erlauben. Eine Umstellung wie `Die Ferien sind es.` funktioniert nur, wenn das "es" ein Korrelat oder Referent ist. Ein Tausch wie `Das Beste sind Ferien` ist ebenfalls nicht möglich, ohne den Ausdruck von Existenz zu verlieren. (Also das "es", das ersetzt wird, muss ein Referent sein).

Ganz klar ist, dass es kein Korrelat sein kann.

Bei einem Platzhalter könnten wir `Ferien sind.` sagen, oder? Normalerweise stellen wir das Subjekt zum Objekt oder das Verb ist intransitiv: `Es schloss der Laden`, `Der Laden schloss`, `Es dreht einem der Kopf`, `Einem dreht der Kopf`.
Für den Platzhalter spricht, dass es ersetzt `Heute sind Ferien.`, `Es sind Ferien heute`, und nicht umgestellt werden kann.
Außerdem:

> *Ich glaube, dass es Ferien sind.
> Ich glaube, dass Ferien sind.

Was ist dieses "es"? Es sprechen hiernach mehr Argumente für den Platzhalter.

> Was ist heute?
> Ferien sind.

Comment: Ich finde die Frage unklar, und vermute fehlenden Kontext als Ursache. Das Beispiel *Strafarbeiten sind nicht erfreulich. Ferien sind es.* erscheint mir korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Ich folge deiner Analyse, dass es ein Platzhalter (expletiv/Vorfeld-Es) ist. Das "es" muss notwendigerweise verschwinden, wenn das Vorfeld besetzt ist, wie du bemerkt hast. Wäre es unpersönlich, hieße es

> *Meiner Meinung nach sind es Ferien.

Ich würde sagen, dass es nicht am "es" liegt, dass "Ferien sind" nicht grammatikalisch ist.

Es ist vielmehr ein Problem des **Satzbaus**: In dieser Art von Satz scheint es unmöglich "Ferien" ins Vorfeld zu stellen. Das betrifft

> - *Ferien sind.
> - *Ferien sind nach meiner Ansicht.

Der Satz

> Ferien sind morgen.

kann nur als "Die Ferien sind morgen, nicht z.B. heute" gelesen werden, während

> Laut Google sind Ferien morgen.

je nach Betonung auch die Bedeutung wie in "Es sind Ferien" haben kann.
Diese Aversion für die erste Position geht so weit, dass sich auch der Nebensatz

> Ich glaube, dass Ferien sind.

sich für mich nicht ganz korrekt anhört. Aber

> Ich glaube, dass es Ferien sind.

ist auf jeden Fall falsch. Ich würde dann einfach

> Ich glaube, dass gerade Ferien sind.

vorziehen. Dann ist Ferien nicht in der ersten Position, und der Satz hört sich gänzlich natürlich an.

Answer (score 0):

Nach dieser [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73503/1696) kommt für mich Option 2 *unpersönliches Es* (das Argument, dass dann ein Positionswechsel möglich sein müsste, überzeugt mich bei diesem Beispiel nicht) oder Option 4 *Expletivum* in Frage, die Argumente aus der Frage für *Platzhalter* halte ich für etwas bemüht.

Comment: Was soll "Expletivum" sein? Die Dudengrammatik definiert alle 3 Typen von "es" als Expletiva und gibt dann genauere Bezeichnungen. Neben Platzhalter, unpersönlich und Korrelat sehe ich keine weiteren Typen von Expletivum. Die Antwort in der verlinkten Frage gibt under "Expletives es" einfach nur das Platzhalter-es an. Ich rufe am Dienstag mal bei Duden an und berichte dann die Ergebnisse hier.